# Maven package error: An attached artifact must have a different ID than its corresponding main artifact

Tags: java, spring, maven

Geting this error on: mvn package

It fails to build every time with the same error, I've tried renaming the artifact, as well as changing dependencies for build in the pom file. Please see more details below:

Any help would be very much appreciated.
error:

```
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.599 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-09-29T14:49:45+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/379M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.1.7.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project compiled: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.1.7.RELEASE:repackage failed: For artifact {com.phil-hudson:compiled:1.0-SNAPSHOT:war}: An attached artifact must have a different ID than its corresponding main artifact. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.phil-hudson</groupId>
    <artifactId>compiled</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>

    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8-b01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-promoted-b65</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.7.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>disney-product-feed</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.13:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:7.0.54:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:7.0.54:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:7.0.54:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.9.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- com.wordnik:swagger-jaxrs_2.10:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.wordnik:swagger-core_2.10:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.10:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jsonSchema:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.wordnik:swagger-annotations:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.json4s:json4s-ext_2.10:jar:3.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.joda:joda-convert:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.json4s:json4s-native_2.10:jar:3.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.json4s:json4s-core_2.10:jar:3.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.10:jar:3.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.scala-lang:scalap:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        \- org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.10:jar:3.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.8:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:11.0.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |     +- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |     \- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |        \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.8-b01:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:2.16:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2-promoted-b65:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-servlet-api:jar:8.0.12:compile
[INFO] \- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:provided
```

Comment: I think this is specific to the spring-boot-maven-plugin rather than a general maven issue. Just in case, run `mvn dependency:tree` then look and see if you have artifacts with conflicting names.

Comment: Thanks for this, I ran it and it looks okay to me.. I updated my question with the output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like a bug in `spring-boot-maven-plugin` together with your version of Maven.

As far as I can tell, Maven knows that the WAR plugin will generate the file `target/compiled-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war`. when it asks the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` for its output, it will get the same name. Since Maven doesn't know what the plugin does, it will assume that both are configured to create the same output file and stop since that can't be what you want (the files will overwrite each other).

Try with the latest version of Maven or file a bug against the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. Let them know which version of Maven you're using.

Comment: Yes, I simply got rid of the Spring WAR plugin and it worked, there must've been some conflict but it wasn't well handled in the logs.

Answer (score 14):

As Dimitri suggested, I solved this by adding `classifier` to spring-boot-maven-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <classifier>boot</classifier>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am currently facing the same issue.
However, providing the required parameter *finalName*, I can see that the .war file is well boot-ified.
Please note that I still encounter the error message in both cases (with and without the *finalName*).

Here is the link to the issue I opened on the Spring Boot project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2060

Answer (score 1):

All that is required is to include a `<finalName>` tag in the `build` section.

```
<build>
    <finalName>myJar</finalName>
</build>
```