# Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to rename

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to build a JAR file out of a spring project. When I try to do a maven install, it throws me the following error

```
Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project ABC: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to rename 'ABC-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar' to 'ABC-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.original' ->
```

The 'pom' file is as shown below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ABC</groupId>
    <artifactId>ABC</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The build part of the pom file is as shown below

```
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Set a compiler level -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- For Generating the Jar File -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>ABCapp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Generating jar file which has Spring boot application -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                    <layout>JAR</layout>
                    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I tried to look in SO and other forums for a possible solution. But none of them worked. Any pointers as to where the problem might be ?

Comment: Can you try if removing the dependency plugin execution fixes the issue?

Comment: You are mixing different Spring Boot version just use a single version ...best is to let Spring Boot decide which version of libs you are using...Spring Boot 1.5.X uses Spring 4.X and not 5.X if you like to use Spring 5.X you have to use Spring Boot 2.X...

Answer (score 0):

While the problem did not completely disappear, what solved the problem for **now** is by using the answer from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101652/maven-package-error-an-attached-artifact-must-have-a-different-id-than-its-corr?rq=1)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <classifier>boot</classifier>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It now creates an additional *.jar file (ABC-boot.jar).

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: check for special characters in the Jar name**

In my case, the problem was related to these lines in the pom.xml:

```
<version>1.0.0-${maven.build.timestamp}</version>
<maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
```

Interestingly, this is OS specific - I got the same error as the asker when doing a `mvn clean install`. It worked on Linux.